# Angular Material Datepicker Validation Error Remains after model is updated

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-material

I'm using two of Angular Material's [datepickers](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/datepicker) to implement a date range input. One of the pickers is the start date, the other is the end date. The start date's md-max-date value is the model that the end date's input is bound to.

```
    <md-input-container class="searchParams" style="margin-left: 0px;">
      <label>Keyrec Start</label>
      <md-datepicker name="startDate" required md-hide-icons="calendar" ng-model="$ctrl.KeysheetViewService.startDate"
        md-max-date="$ctrl.KeysheetViewService.endDate"></md-datepicker>
      <div ng-messages="keysheetSearch.startDate.$error">
        <div ng-message="required">
          Please pick a date
        </div>
      </div>
    </md-input-container>
    <md-input-container class="searchParams">
      <label>Keyrec End</label>
      <md-datepicker name="endDate" required md-hide-icons="calendar" ng-model="$ctrl.KeysheetViewService.endDate"
        md-min-date="$ctrl.KeysheetViewService.startDate" md-max-date="$ctrl.currDate"></md-datepicker>
      <div ng-messages="keysheetSearch.endDate.$error">
        <div ng-message="required">
          Please pick a date
        </div>
      </div>
    </md-input-container>
```

Say I have start date populated with 05/01/2017, and end Date populated with 05/02/2017. If I click into the input form of start date, and manually type in a date that is later than 05/02/2017, the form will recognize the error and turn red.

This is the expected behavior. But when I correct the end date to be later than the start date (expecting this to remove the error) the error remains.

[Error remains when end date is past start date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4sH6.png)

Anybody else had this issue? Any suggestions for a solution?

Comment: can you put your minimal code in plunker to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @tanmay will do.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/UOicD9ypEKTFZ0yq8RBc?p=preview

Comment: here is [updated plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ufl7KpYfdag6BOql7O9w?p=preview). You has missed `ngMessages` included in index.html and in module dependency

Comment: Thank you for the catch, but that solution doesn't appear to resolve the bug. When I use your plunk, if I populated the start date with 04/05/17, and the end date with 04/10/17, and then manually type the start date to be 04/15/17, I see the validation error, as expected. However, when I correct the end date to be 04/20/17 (which should remove the validation error), the error of "maxdate" still remains on start date. Also, if you answer be sure to put your response in the "Answers" section so I can thumb your response up. Thanks!

Comment: Upon further review, it would appear that the datepicker's input model doesn't get updated when the input is invalid. Which means that while the validation error appears, the start date has not been updated to the invalid date selected. This prevents the error from disappearing when the end date is changed, even though visually the inputs appear to be correct.

Comment: well it works fine with me unless I'm missing your point.. are you sure you typed your dates correctly in the ^^comment ? if yes, can you create a gif or something to describe error?